# QT loading images at runtime from a folder in the deploy bundle after linuxdeployqt run

Tags: image, qt, deployment, runtime, loading

I need to read all the images / files from a folder that I'll create in the release folder after the use of **linuxdeployqt**. For now the only images I managed to use are those which are listed in the qrc.qml file, but them are embedded in the binary.

I tried this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    QDir directory("file:/arts");
    QStringList artList = directory.entryList(QStringList("*.*"));

    for (int i=0; i<artList.size(); i++) {
        debugText += artList.at(i) + "\n";
        qDebug() << "----> list element: " << artList.at(i);
    }

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("artModel", QVariant::fromValue(artList));
    
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;
    return app.exec(); }
```

but it founds a folder arts inside qrc.

**edit:**
I am trying another approach to the problem, managing the files from the qml side.

```js
Rectangle {
    property int currentIndex: 0
    property int tot_anim: 3
    property string videoUrl: "file:///img/%1.gif"
    property bool swiping: false
    color: "transparent"

    AnimatedImage {
        id: anim_0
        source: "file:///img/0.gif"
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        fillMode: AnimatedImage.PreserveAspectCrop
        z: 10
    }
    ...
}
```

But also in this case at runtime it doesn't find the `/img` folder.

Comment: Are you saying there's a path in your qrc that is the same as a path in your file system? I wouldn't expect that to cause a problem since you're specifying `"file:/"`. Does it work correctly if you rename one of the paths so they don't match?

Comment: Hi JarMan, thank you for your reply. I tried renaming the folder to /img and pointing at it with the path "file:/img", but nothing found. No error occurred but the debug string that should contain the list of files' name is empty.

Comment: use correct file prefix "files://" then whatever path .. if your actual path is "/arts" , then use "file:///arts"

Comment: Hi Mohammad Kanan, thank you. I tried also to use `file:///img` to point the folder, but nothing different happened. If I don't indicate anything else, this should mean that the folder is a the same path of the executable, correct? I also created the same folder (/img) in a path that QTCreator indicates me when I launch the project (XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root')